# Is it possible to separate menu entry and event string in PySimpleGui right-click menus?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Is it possible to separate the menu entry in a [right-click menu](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#right-click-menus) from the event string that is assigned when the event is thrown?

E.g., when adding a right-click menu to a list box via

```py
sg.Listbox(
  "",
  key="-eventListbox-",
  size=(50, 10),
  right_click_menu = ['&Right', ['Open']],
  select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED,
  enable_events=True,
),
```

the right-click on an item will trigger an event "Open". I would prefer the event to be named "-eventOpen-" (or something similar), but not necessarily the string in the menu item.

Comment: Try 'Open::optional_key', it will show `Open`, but with key 'Open::optional_key'. Refer https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#menu-definition

Comment: Ah, this might be a solution, thanks! I am not complaining, but my preferred solution would have been to return "optional_key" rather than "Open::optional_key", but I will be able to work with that as well. (The proposed solution will create inconsistent keys, if you are following the guideline to name keys "-ABC-").

Comment: I have now added a piece of code that looks for "::" in the event string and removes it. That way I can continue to use my code which looks for event keys following the guideline.